# Difficult partition question Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2,  & 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 \\[2ex]  
x+1, & 1 < x ≤ 2
\end{cases}
$$

Let $ε > 0$ be given

**Question**

Let $n ∈ \mathbb N$ be given. Explain why there is a Partition $P = \{\mathbf{X}_0,\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{X}_k\}$ of the interval $[0, 1- 1/n]$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^k (M_i-m_i)(X_i - X_{i-1}) < 1/3ε$

Guys I have absolutely no idea what they are asking here...my first course in real analysis and im finding it very difficult, help will be so much appreciated

Comment: What does M and m stand for?

Comment: By $M_i$ and $m_i$ they mean the maximum and the minimum of $f(x)$ in the interval $[X_{i-1},X_i]$? If this is so, this is not hard

Comment: This doesn't look right. Are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: Yes They mean M is defined as the suprema and m the m the infimum...Yes it probably isn't as it is an introductory course in Analysis, but still im not use to these type of questions

Comment: I have revised and yes im sure i copied it exactly from our assignment

Comment: Hint: $f(x)$ is increasing so you know $m_i, M=i$.

Comment: Hey guys our lecturer posted this morning that there is a mistake in the question ... it should be 1 < x <= 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using Rudin's book because of your notation. Notice that $f$ is monotonic on $[0,2]$ (In particular on $[0,1-1/n]$, use Theorem 6.9 on Rudin and conclude that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1-1/n]$ . Then, let's say $\varepsilon'=1/3\varepsilon$, since your function is Riemann integrable then using Theorem 6.6, there exists a partition of $[0,1-1/n]$ like $P=\{X_0,...,X_k\}$, such that:
$$
U(P,f) - L(P,f) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}(M_i-m_{i})(X_i - X_{i-1}) < \varepsilon'=1/3\varepsilon
$$
If my guess is incorrect, you should check the Integration part in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis to understand how the argument goes, since the theorems I mentioned have long proofs and is better for you to read them.